# Shipping containers on-premises + offline networks

Tags: docker

Currently investigating Docker as a way to ship and deploy out applications. Our applications are deployed on-premises (ie: at customer sites), on networks that are usually secured with no internet access.

Is there any solutions out there geared towards packaging and shipping Docker images in an offline environment?

The only thing I can think of is to package the images using `docker save`, ship it to site as our software deliverable, and importing it locally with `docker load`.

Any other alternatives out there?

Comment: A few years later but I'm in a similar situation. What did you end up going with @zedix?

Comment: I found nothing promising. We ended up ditching the container solution :(

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I made the same decision after doing research, seems like the tooling around containers just isn't suited to an offline environment.